# ffmpeg stream videos from two cams have a same device name

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

There are two cameras have a same device name **Microsoft® LifeCam Studio(TM)**.
`ffmpeg -list_deivces true -f dshow -i dummy` prints the below output.

```
C:\Users\user>ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
ffmpeg version git-2020-02-05-e6891d1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 39.100 / 56. 39.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.101 / 58. 67.101
  libavformat    58. 37.100 / 58. 37.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 74.100 /  7. 74.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]  "Microsoft┬« LifeCam Studio(TM)"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0811&mi_00#8&6ae46e6&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]  "Microsoft┬« LifeCam Studio(TM)"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0811&mi_00#8&e544916&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]  "Desktop Microphone (6- Microsoft┬« LifeCam Studio(TM))"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{D5F4881A-6E88-4563-8BA0-081CFD50E353}"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]  "Desktop Microphone (5- Microsoft┬« LifeCam Studio(TM))"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{84674B28-DC68-4AC0-8331-D687C7B7D69C}"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]  "Digital Audio (S/PDIF) (High Definition Audio Device)"
[dshow @ 000001d5c5108dc0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{CDD24485-59D2-4BED-B6FC-B7447251C7E2}"
```

Because the two cameras have a same device name, I couldn't stream two videos using this simple command at a same time: `ffplay -f dshow -i video=Microsoft® LifeCam Studio(TM)`.
So I used pin names following the [ffmpeg dshow example](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Examples-2).
The only thing I could check was `Could not find video device with name [video=~~pin name~~] among source devices of type video.`

What `ffplay` command makes enable to stream both videos?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to distinguish between identical cameras in Libav/ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510699/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-cameras-in-libav-ffmpeg)

Comment: @aergistal I checked the way to use video_device_number with an argument 0 and 1 for each camera. ffplay for video device number 0 plays video stream but it prints “Could not run graph (sometimes caused by a device already in use by other application)” error with device number 1

Answer (score 4):

I got into same situation with these cheap HDMI capture USB dongles. With careful reading answer is on the page: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow

Same name dshow devices are indexed by ffmepg. In Windows you add " -video_device_number xxx" between "-f dshow" and "-i" device name. Switch name is different for other platform but syntax is very similar.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_device_number 0 -i video="USB Video" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ffmpeg \
    -rtbufsize 10MB -f dshow -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0811&mi_00#8&6ae46e6&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global" \
    -rtbufsize 10MB -f dshow -i video="@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_045e&pid_0811&mi_00#8&e544916&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global" \
    -filter_complex hstack,format=yuv420p -f sdl -
```

If you have an error, change another USB Port.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack